# '"The compiler option dagger.hilt.android.internal.projectType is not a recognized Hilt option" - Android Hilt with multi module project

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger, dagger-hilt, kapt

I have a project and recently we converted the project to a multi module.
However I could not run the module it gives me this error.

I think I made something wrong with the dependencies and some configurations.
Following is my `app/build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.protobuf'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'

}
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'


android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 33
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        dataBinding true
    }
    packagingOptions{
        pickFirst "androidsupportmultidexversion.txt"
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    hilt {
        enableAggregatingTask = true
    }
    namespace '##.###.########.###############'
}

dependencies {
    def lifecycle_version = "2.5.1"
    def roomVersion = "2.4.3"
    def nav_version = "2.5.3"

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

    // UI Tests
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.2.1'

    //Material Design
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'

    def fragments_version = "1.5.2"
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragments_version"
    // ViewModel
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version")
    // ViewModel utilities for Compose
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:$lifecycle_version")
    // LiveData
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version")
    // Lifecycles only (without ViewModel or LiveData)
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version")
    // Annotation processor
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"
    // To use Kotlin annotation processing tool (kapt)
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion")
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")
    // optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion")
    // Coroutines
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.2")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.2")

    // Kotlin
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
    kapt "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-metadata-jvm:0.5.0"


    //Criptografia
    implementation 'com.madgag.spongycastle:bctls-jdk15on:1.58.0.0'

    //AWS SDK for Android
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.51.0'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-core:2.51.0'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-iot:2.36.0'

    implementation 'com.amplifyframework:aws-auth-cognito:1.37.1'

    implementation 'com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.55'

    implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.2.5'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.1'

    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.2.1"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1'

    // Coil
    implementation "io.coil-kt:coil-compose:1.4.0"

    //Protobuf
    apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'
    implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.0'

    //Barber
    implementation("app.cash.barber:barber:0.3.3")

    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.3.0'

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    // G800 Lib
    implementation(name: 'libgedi-0.190121.gpos800', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'SatGerLib', ext: 'aar')

    //Dagger Hilt
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.43.2'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.43.2'

    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.4.0'

    implementation ('io.socket:socket.io-client:2.0.1') {
        // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }

    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.11'

    //Encryption
    implementation "androidx.security:security-crypto:1.0.0"

    //UNZIP
    implementation "org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.21"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    //GPS
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'

    //QR CODE GENERATOR
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.4.1'

    //Gson
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.1'

    /* Retrofit */
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okHttpVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okHttpInterceptorVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.4.0"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0'
    }
    plugins {
        javalite {
            artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0'
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                remove java
            }
            task.plugins {
                javalite { }
            }
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

And this one is `dev/build.gradle`(submodule)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'

}

android {
    namespace 'br.com.###.dev'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.###.dev"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    packagingOptions{
        pickFirst "androidsupportmultidexversion.txt"
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    hilt {
        enableAggregatingTask = true
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':app')
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'
    implementation(name: 'libgedi-0.190121.gpos800', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'SatGerLib', ext: 'aar')

    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.43.2'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.43.2'
}
```

And this is the top level `build.gradle` file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url='https://jitpack.io'}

    }
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.2.1'
        /* Http */
        retrofitVersion = "2.9.0"
        okHttpVersion = "4.10.0"
        okHttpInterceptorVersion = "4.10.0"
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.18'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.20'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:1.7.20"
        classpath "com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-gradle-plugin:2.4.6"

        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.44.2'

        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }


    }
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app\src\main\java\packagename\MyApplication.kt

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApplication: Application()
```

I can post other files if you need to see. Now I did not want to make it look complicated.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have updated the libraries like `implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.44'` Then also I added this plugin to both build.gradle files of the modules => `id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'` Now I get different error => `  Application class annotated with @HiltAndroidApp has to be defined in an android application project`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment, first I updated libraries so they match in all build.gradle files. In this case it gave another error.  Then I opened an [issue to dagger github repo](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/3647) and they answered like this:

```
Application class annotated with @HiltAndroidApp has to be defined in an android application project
```

> This means that your @HiltAndroidApp annotated class is currently
> defined in a library module (i.e. a build.gradle file with plugins {
> id 'com.android.library' }, which is not allowed. Instead, you need to
> move that class into the application module (i.e. a build.gradle file
> with plugins {id 'com.android.application'}.

So lastly we moved the application class to module dev and also we put an application class inside of the library module too but we did not add @HiltAndroidApp.
So it looks like this (library module):

```
class MyApplication
```

And application module:

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApplication: Application()
```

And obviously we adjusted manifest files too.
Also we got several errors too but we fixed them by searching from google.
Key part was adding hilt application class inside of the dev/module.
I hope it helps who has similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error message, but have a different solution. I just had to update hilt and kapt versions. I copied hilt and kapt version from the docs and it wasn't the latest one. What I did is, in android studio, right click app module, go to 'open module settings' and go to 'suggestions'. I had a suggestion to update my modules, I guess to the newest stable versions, and it fixed the problem. You can of course find the versions on the internet, but using the IDE might be more convinient.